# Standalone source code of gethostbyname function for linux

Tags: c++, linux, dns

Where i can get source code of `gethostbyname` which can be used without linking other libs(just sockets) for linux?

I found this:
https://github.com/gnif/ARMT/blob/master/common/CDNS.cc

But this doesn't work, error when resolving

Thanks!

Comment: Remember that you still have to link with the standard library, for the sockets and other functions, so when the standard library includes host-name resolution why not use it? Also remember that by default the standard library is linked _dynamically_ so no extra space on disk will be used. The only reason to not use the standard library for this would be in an embedded system where space is severely limited, and then you wouldn't use the GNU libc anyway but `gethostname` would still probably be in the standard library.

Answer (score 2):

"A non-blocking DNS resolver library in a single .c file. Supports both stub and recursive modes."

http://25thandclement.com/~william/projects/dns.c.html

Answer (score 1):

DNS resolution is complicated. Why *not* use a library? I use c-ares when I need one.

If you don't want to use it as a library you can stuff all its source code files directly into your project although that would be weird.

Answer (score 1):

`gethostbyname` is anything but simple, as it has to find out what the currently configured source for such data is (local files, NIS, NIS+, DNS, perhaps others), in which order to search there, what to do if the lookup for each one fails (`nsswitch.conf(5)` et al), and do the looking up and miscelaneous bookkeeping and caching.